# Changing the background color of C# wpf checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have made a C# wpf application using [Mahapps](http://www.mahapps.com) with Visual Studio 2012. I have added a check box into it. I want to change the inner background color of the checkbox. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the appearance of your control by using the **ControlTemplate** of that control. Just modify it as per your requirement.

See this [MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Where should I add that code ?

Comment: First show your code. What you have done so far ??